# MySQL Update with Sub Select for ACF Repeater Count

Tags: mysql, wordpress, custom-fields, advanced-custom-fields, post-meta

My Wordpress database somehow got messed up.

I am using ACF repeater fields and the repeater count shows zero even though I have as many as 12 repeating elements.

I am trying to update the repeater count so the field values will properly display in admin.

```
update  wp.sd_postmeta set meta_key = ( SELECT count(*) as count FROM wp.sd_postmeta where meta_key like 'child_products_%_sku%' and post_id = pid) where meta_key like 'child_products' and post_id = pid
```

or

```
update  wp.sd_postmeta set meta_key = ( SELECT count(*) as count FROM wp.sd_postmeta where meta_key like 'child_products_%_sku%' and post_id = pid) where meta_key like 'child_products' and post_id = pid
```

The question is, how do I generate a value for pid?   I'd like to loop over all of the posts with a meta_key of child_products.

Comment: What about querying first to find the pid's that contain the repeater field then running the update against only those posts?

Comment: I could do that.    Thanks for the suggestion.  Was hoping I overlooked something simple though.